# Assign license to multiple users

Tags: profile, user-management

I have read several posts but not able to get the exact answer. I am creating a recruiting demo app in which there various profiles like:

- Recruiter
- Hiring manager
- Interviewers

I need to create users and assign a Profile to them. I cannot activate more than 2 users (either by salesforce or by salesforce platform license).

Is there any way I can assign a license to multiple users? I tried to put some effort by permission test, but I am not getting any resolution on that.

Answer (score 1):

Developer Editions come with 2 Salesforce Licences - so you can have two active user accounts on there at any one time. You can't have more than that, and Salesforce are very unlikely to facilitate this.

You options would be:

1) If you have a legitimate Demo proposal, and are a legitimate ISV, you might be able to talk Salesforce into provisioning an ISV Partner Org, which has 10 licences available. You will need to speak to an AE about that (if you don't have contact with an AE, you won't be a candidate for a partner Org)

2) You can activate/deactivate as many users as you like so long as only 2 are active **at any one time** so you can make your extra Recruiters and Hiring Managers and just de-activate the one you don't need as you activate and login as the other. You could have 20 inactive users in the list, so long as only 2 were then "on".